# Alternatives to The Statistical Sleuth?

Tags: anova, t-test, references

I am looking for a simple and concise book on statistics (t-test, ANOVA and all its variants, linear regression, etc.), centered on data analysis. I am not interested in theory or proofs, but just want to know what test is appropriate under what conditions, preferably with some real world examples. E.g., "An Introduction to Statistical Learning" by G. James et al. does this for machine learning.

The only book I could find that vaguely fits that description is "The Statistical Sleuth," but it's not available at my local library. Is there any other alternative like that?

Comment: If the condition is *available at my local library*, how are we supposed to advise you without knowing what books your library has? Why don't you do an interlibrary loan?

Comment: " but just want to know what test is appropriate under what conditions," no book can in good faith cover the extensive possible list of all tests and all conditions. A digestable intro-level text would be "Applied Linear Regression Models" by Neter Kutner, Wasserman, and Nachtsheim.

Comment: Is there a particular field that you work in? There are some really good discipline specific texts that are much more targetted...

Comment: My suggestion is to read notes posted by colleges. Penn State has a lot of good material that we consulted during graduate school (which was not at Penn State).

Comment: One classic applied statistics book that has been through enough editions that you might find a copy of some edition available: Ott & Longnecker: Statistical Methods and Data Analysis.

Comment: AdamO already hit the nail on the head, but I want to add that it doesn't even make sense to instantly resort to *tests* as you mention. Tests are but a fraction of the available statistical methods and are in my opinion grossly overused. By skipping the theory, you limit the type of question you can answer to the methods you are familiar with.

Comment: *Statistical Sleuth* is quite good. Chapter 3 for example, covers in detail what the effect of each assumption (normality and same SD) means for using of t-tools with examples. R-cran-projects has some associated R code in knitr along with it [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Sleuth3/), which covers in some detail the case studies used in the book chapter by chapter.

Comment: What about interlibrary loan?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think either of these is exactly a substitute for Statistical Sleuth (which I also like) but it's a pair of books that will help a lot:

1. *Statistics* by Freedman, Pisani and Purves.  A really good text that will teach you a lot but won't overwhelm you with math.
2. *Statistics as Principled Argument* by Robert Abelson. An excellent and very informal guide to using statistics sensibly, particularly in the "soft" sciences.

Answer (score 0):

I looked through the Statistical Sleuth.  At least what I saw seemed pretty good...  A lot of learning about analysis of experiments is an interactive process. You will probably want to have several different textbooks, and then you will want to supplement this with online searches about how to conduct these analyses in your chosen software program. Understanding what the software is doing is really important.  It doesn't always do what you think it's supposed to do... As a caveat, I would say to take no advice as the gospel truth, even if it's in a textbook written by a statistician.  A lot of analysis of experiments is based on judgement.  This can be frustrating to students trying to learn.  E.g. t-tests are robust to violations of normality, but they're not infinitely robust.  There's no test that's going to tell you if it's okay to use a t-test for a data set. You just have to look at the data honestly, know what are your alternatives for analysis, and know what you are trying to achieve. Sometimes authors give bad advice about how to approach these problems, for example recommending using a test to test for normality or homoscedasticity. That's a simple solution that may not be the best advice. You also have to remember that people writing a textbook or a blog are trying make concepts and procedures understandable.  There are probably many considerations and subtleties that they are excluding...

Okay, so a few recommendations for text books.

Conover, Practical Nonparametric Statistics

Agresti, Categorical Data Analysis

Zar, Biostatistical Analysis

I'm sure I have a bunch of other suggestions.  This really needs to be updated, but I have some resources [here](http://rcompanion.org/handbook/A_04.html).

Otherwise, I'll offer a couple of online resources, both written by non-statisticians.  Caveat: I'm the author of the second, and affiliated with the first.

http://www.biostathandbook.com/

http://rcompanion.org/handbook/